# Optimization: Jsf Bean getter with direct EJB call

Tags: jsf, optimization, primefaces, ejb, managed-bean

Let's look at this simple example:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{MyBean.getList(MyOtherBean.id)}" paginator="true">
...
</p:dataTable>
```

With two versions of an implementations of "MyBean" (MyOtherBean doesn't matter, it just gives some id):

```
@ManagedBean(name = "MyBean")
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean {

    @EJB
    private Service service;

    public List<Data> getList(long id) {
        return service.getListFromDatabase(id);
    }
}
```

versus:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "MyBean")
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean {

    @EJB
    private Service service;
    private List<Data> list
    private long id;

    public List<Data> getList(long id) {
        if(list == null || this.id != id) {
            this.id = id;
            list = service.getListFromDatabase(id);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

After initial loading of the page with the first given rows, just do some simple pagination. Therefore the getter is called serveral times.

The first method needs 2000ms for a database call with about 300 elements. The second version only needs 200ms, because of the cached elements (Time is measured by the browser, given the waiting time).

But that seems to be some kind of premature optimization. And as we all know, premature optimization is the root of all evil. Isn't there some automatic caching in the beans, or perhaps at the database level.

Is my above optimization a usual way to go with such things?

PS: yeah i know i can do lazy loading, but if database call is always that expensive, it would be faster to just load all things once, and let the caching stuff in the view scoped bean.

Thanks for your opinion!

Comment: Make the bean request scoped, and load the data on the @post-construct. Otherwise the second options is the best option. I don't see any pre-mature optimization 2s to 0.2s is not a premature optimization

Comment: If i put request scope, every call loads for 2s. Because pagination does several requests. Everytime, a new page is requested, the requestBean would be created again, causes always the long load. 

But yeah i'll go for the second one